# Multiple Azure Functions in one Timer trigger class

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We have to write multiple triggers. I was hoping to create separate functions, based on the trigger types. So if I need 5 timer triggers, that will run at different times, I would create one Timer trigger function class and name the functions like `[TimerTrigger1]`, `[TimerTrigger2]`, `[TimerTrigger3]` ... and so forth. After I added the code I am not sure if I can do that anymore.

Can someone suggest how I can go about adding multiple triggers? I can't have two `Run` functions under one class.

```cs
public static class TimerTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("InsertTimerTrigger1")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
         // Do task 1
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    [FunctionName("InsertTimerTrigger2")]
    public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        //Do Task 2
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create multiple functions in Single Class. You can change `Run` Method name.

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Method1([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static void Method2([TimerTrigger("0 */3 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```

But I will recommend, Create multiple functions will help you (5 in your case).

1. If you are using common business logic, you can put in a common class and inject in all function.
2. You can independently Enable/Disable/Delete function from FunctionApp Instance.

[image]

3. You can monitor each function independently (from Function Monitor section)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj, I am a bit confused about FunctionApp instance and Function Monitor Section? Can you please give an example of those.  I am developing all in visual studio 2019 .net core project.

Comment: Also, how can I enable/Disable functions?

Comment: @Sarah I added Screenshot from Azure portal. Once you will deploy your function App you can see Monitor and Enable/Disable Tab from the portal.

Comment: that was really helpful. I got my functions running based on different timers within one class now.

Comment: @Sarah Please Accept my answer if this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 6):

You can choose any name for the methods. (Naming it as "Run" is not a requirement.)

```cs
public static class TimerTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("InsertTimerTrigger1")]
    public static void InsertTimerTrigger1([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
         // Do task 1
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }

    [FunctionName("InsertTimerTrigger2")]
    public static void InsertTimerTrigger2([TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
        //Do Task 2
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
}
```